# how same operating system works on different hardware(machines)?

Tags: operating-system

I have question regarding operating systems. how same operating system works on different hardware(machines)?
For example Windows7 will work on both intel and AMD processors. But they have different machine languages. So how same operating system works on different hardware(machines)?

Comment: because Operating systems are written in high level languages like C and a little assembly but not directly in machine code.

Comment: That is true. But for example reading data operation intel use machine code like 10101010 but AMD may use 11110000 (different code). Then how same operating system work with different machines?

Comment: `Intel` and `AMD` are companies which manufacture various processors, some of them having completely compatible [instruction set architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set), like the very popular [x86-64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Differences_between_AMD64_and_Intel_64). Either search for your answer at [Super User Stack Exchange](http://superuser.com/) site or make your question more specific, practical and [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

That is what the compilers and libraries are for.  They convert the high level language(C,Fortran,Ruby,etc) into the low level language-assembly language.

You install libraries based on your processor and bit width(32/64).
Chip manufacturers work with companies like Microsoft to provide an interface layer between the OS code and their chips.  The install program identifies the chip type and provides the appropriate layer. Thats why the package says it works with Intel, AMD, Cyrix, etc.

Sometimes the OS will not have the capability to talk to newly installed hardware.  Thats why you have to install drivers.

Comment: So, same operating system software work with intel, amd and cyrix processors?